# Is Python's asyncio `loop.create_task(...)` threadsafe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have matplotlib running on the main thread with a live plot of data coming in from an external source. To handle the incoming data I have a simple UDP listener listening for packages using asyncio with the event loop running on a seperate thread.

I now want to add more sources and I'd like to run their listeners on the same loop/thread as the first one. To do this I'm just passing the loop object to the classes implementing the listeners and their constructor adds a task to the loop that will initialize and run the listener.

However since these classes are initialized in the main thread I'm calling the `loop.create_task(...)` function from there instead of the loop's thread. Will this cause any issues?

Comment: Answer is no. I'll elaborate in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, using `loop.create_task(...)` to schedule a coroutine from a different thread is not threadsafe, use [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) instead.